# About sphinx segment rules

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sphinx

When I use sphinx, I found the results are not quite accurate.

For example, in my mysql table, there are records with 'test1', 'test2', 'test.zip', 'test_zip', 'test-zip'
When I search for 'test', only got 'test.zip' and 'test-zip'. And if I want to get 'test1' in result, I have to search 'test1' explicitly

So my question is, why sphinx not consider test1 as 'test' and '1', and if I want the search results including the part of a full word, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The default charset_table, sets letters, numbers and underscore to be word charactors, everything else is a seperator.

So `test1` would be indexed as "test1" but `test-zip` would be indexed as "test zip"

There is infix/prefix indexing
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-infix-len
so can match part words. (sphinx by default always matches whole words)

If you want you could change charset_table, so numbers are not considered word charactors (but wouldnt then be able to search for numbers!) - at the same time would probably want to not include underscore - so taht `test_zip` could be considered as two words.

You could instead put numbers in blend_chars - so that they are taken as seperators too.

Finally could use regexp_filter to split up words and numbers into separate words.

... so four possible solutions, possibly worthwhile to try each one, and decide which works best for you overall.